# How run my flutter project on iOS (on my Linux machine)?

Tags: flutter

Android studio 4.0

Linux Mint 19.3

I create my simple Flutter project and success run it on my Android device.
Nice.

But now I need to run my Flutter project on iPhone. So... to do this I need... what I need?

Maybe install iOS on Virtual Box (on my Linux machine) and then install XCode and then run my Flutter project on XCode? Or maybe has another approach?

Comment: You have to be running XCode, which only exists for MacOC, which legally only runs on MacBooks and iMacs. You would have to run a VM of MacOS to be able to make an iOS build.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CI/CD services like Codemagic

[How to develop and distribute iOS apps without Mac with Flutter & Codemagic](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-develop-and-distribute-ios-apps-without-mac-with-flutter-codemagic/)